# Как изменить свойства user agent stylesheet в Chrome?

Tags: html, css

В браузерах  Chrome и  Mazila разное отображение выпадающего списка.Значение первого option в выпадающем списке сливается с верхним краем в браузере Chrome. В Mazilla нормально отображается. user agent stylesheet имеет свойство padding: 0px 2px 1px - мне нужно 0px(top) изменить на 2px... КАК мне повлиять на него?
Есть верстка:

```
<select class="select_class">
    <option> 1 </option>
    <option> 2 </option>
    <option> 3 </option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
.select_class {
    background-color:red; /* срабатывает */
    margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px ; /* не срабатывает */
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px; /* не срабатывает */
}
```

user agent stylesheet в Chrome:

```
option {
font-weight: normal;
display: block;
white-space: pre;
min-height: 1.2em;
padding: 0px 2px 1px; /* нужно изменить 0 на 2px*/ 
}
```

Comment: Выполните select кастомным

Comment: @HamSter прописал я select  кастомным....ситуация не изменилась......hfdding и margin не срабатывают...